# Clipping from given point using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, layers, clip

I am working with ModelBuilder and I am trying to clip an area around a certain point.

Is there a tool that I can use in which I can assign it a certain distance from the point.

For instance, if I have a point X and I want to clip an area that is 12.5 miles each direction from the point and then have it as a layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attached is a model that should get you going.  Keep in mind the Clip tool in Analysis is designed to clip vector data, not raster data.  If you need to clip a raster, alter the model and use Clip (Data Management) or Extract by Mask (Spatial Analyst).  Best of luck!

[image]

Comment: Aaron, Thank you very much for your help! Is there a way I could make my Buffer a rectangle or a square instead of a circle? Preferably a square 25 x 25 kilometers.

Comment: No problem, check out the following link to create square buffers: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29340/8104