# Create square buffers around points in QGIS with Python?

Tags: qgis, buffer

I have x, y coordinates in lat/long and I need to create 5x5 degree square cells around them, with the lat/long coordinates being the centroids.

My first option is to create a buffer around the centroids with 1 segment and a distance of 1/2(5°) * sqrt(2) (must multiply by sqrt(2)  bc the tool uses centroid to the corner of the square as the buffer distance, as opposed to centroid to edge), which results in sideways squares around my points, then rotate each feature by 45 degrees. I'd prefer not to do this as the distance isn't as precise and I do not know how to rotate each individual buffer feature quickly.

My second option, which seems much simpler, is to create a buffer around the centroids with the distance I need ((1/2)*5°) and then use something like ArcMap's Feature to Envelope tool.

I see that someone has [the same question here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34891/how-to-automate-the-drawing-of-polygons-square-around-a-number-of-points-in-qg) and an answer was provided, but I have no idea how to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As you wondering in your last paragraph, to do that programmatically with PyQGIS it is not very difficult. You can try out next code. However, I used a shapefile and projected coordinates in meters (buffer has 1000 m). You only would need to do a few changes.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'square_buffer',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    new_feat = QgsFeature()
    new_feat.setAttributes([i])
    tmp_feat = feat.geometry().buffer(1000, -1).boundingBox().asWktPolygon()
    new_feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(tmp_feat))
    prov.addFeatures([new_feat])

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running the above code at the Python Console of QGIS, I got:

[image]

It works.

**Editing Note:**

Next code introduces at the attributes table a column for the x-coordinate, y-coordinate, and ID number for each point.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = [ feat for feat in layer.getFeatures() ]

epsg = layer.crs().postgisSrid()

uri = "Polygon?crs=epsg:" + str(epsg) + "&field=id:integer&field=x:real&field=y:real&field=point_id:integer""&index=yes"

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri,
                           'square_buffer',
                           'memory')

prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()

for i, feat in enumerate(feats):
    point = feat.geometry().asPoint()
    new_feat = QgsFeature()
    new_feat.setAttributes([i, point[0], point[1], feat.id()])
    tmp_feat = feat.geometry().buffer(1000, -1).boundingBox().asWktPolygon()
    new_feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(tmp_feat))
    prov.addFeatures([new_feat])

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mem_layer)
```

After running the new code at the Python Console of QGIS, result was:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How would I modify this so that the final output polygons include the attributes of the points?

Comment: Wich point attributes?

Comment: For example, in my x,y point data the attribute table contains a column for the x-coordinate, y-coordinate, and ID number for each point. I'd like for that information to also be in the attribute table of the resulting square polygons.

Comment: This is another question, however, you have the answer in my **Editing Note**.

Comment: For anybody trying this on QGIS 3 (2.99 at the time of writing this comment), replace `QgsMapLayerRegistry` on the last line with `QgsProject`. For more info see [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244452/is-qgsmaplayerregistry-removed-in-qgis3)

Comment: What does the -1 mean in [ tmp_feat = feat.geometry().buffer(1000, -1).boundingBox().asWktPolygon() ] ?, I could not find it in the api documentation.

Comment: -1 it is the default for a completely circular buffer. By using 1 gets a four sides buffer, 2 gets an eight sides buffer (4+4), 3 gets a twelve sides buffer (8+4) and so on.

Answer (score 4):

QGIS 3 provides a quick and dirty alternative:
- Vector --> Geoprocessing tools --> Buffer

Select your point layer as an input layer, make sure that the end cap style is set to square and the distance should be half of the intended square length (so a 1km-per-side square should have a Distance of 500m).

Answer (score 2):

To transform points into squares you can try `native:buffer` processing algorithm with
 `END_CAP_STYLE` parameter set to `2` (square).

**Warning!** Results may vary and depend on input layer's coordinate system. In exapmle, if you use WGS 84 and set distance to `5000` this will result in a square line of 5000 **degrees** (not meters).

[image]

**Tested with pyQGIS 3.6.1:**

```py
def buffer(input, distance, output, before_processing_reproject_to_epsg_number=None):
    params = {'INPUT': input,
              'DISTANCE': distance,
              'END_CAP_STYLE': 2 , # - 0: Round - 1: Flat - 2: Square
              'DISSOLVE': False,
              'OUTPUT': output}
    feedback = qgis.core.QgsProcessingFeedback()
    alg_name = 'native:buffer'
    # print(processing.algorithmHelp(alg_name)) # tool tips
    result = processing.run(alg_name, params, feedback=feedback)
    return  result
```

Usage example:

```py
buffer_result = buffer(input=r'C:\input.shp', distance=5000, output=r'C:\output.shp')
print(buffer_result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial approach works if you're okay with the precision issue. Calculate the length of half the desired square's diagonal (a2+b2=c2) as this is the length the `Buffer` tool will use for the `Distance` parameter. Input 1 as the `Segment` parameter value. Once the tool has been run all features can be simultaneously rotated using

> Vector geometry -> Rotate tool

.
[image: Vector geometry->Rotate tool]