# Creating square buffers around points using shapely?

Tags: python, geometry, coordinates, buffer

I am trying to create square buffers around given points, I am able to create circular buffers but how do I create square ones?

```
from shapely.ops import transform
from shapely.geometry import Point
    local_azimuthal_projection = "+proj=aeqd +R=6371000 +units=m +lat_0={} +lon_0={}".format(lat, lon)
                    wgs84_to_aeqd = partial(
                        pyproj.transform,
                        pyproj.Proj('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'),
                        pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
                    )
                    aeqd_to_wgs84 = partial(
                        pyproj.transform,
                        pyproj.Proj(local_azimuthal_projection),
                        pyproj.Proj('+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs'),
                    )

                    point_transformed = transform(wgs84_to_aeqd, Point(float(lon), float(lat)))
                    buffer = point_transformed.buffer(0.5*1000)
                    buffered_geom = transform(aeqd_to_wgs84, buffer).exterior.coords[:]
```

Answer (score 20):

Here is how you can create square buffers using [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/). Note that geometric operations in geopandas are performed by shapely.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some sample data 
p1 = Point((1,2))
p2 = Point((6,8))
points = gpd.GeoSeries([p1,p2])

# Buffer the points using a square cap style
# Note cap_style: round = 1, flat = 2, square = 3
buffer = points.buffer(2, cap_style = 3)

# Plot the results
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
buffer.boundary.plot(ax=ax1, color = 'slategrey')
points.plot(ax = ax1, color = 'red')
```

[image]