# Point file to Raster conversion using "geocube"

Tags: python, rasterio, rasterization, raster-conversion, geocube

Problem 1: Whenever I generate raster from a point using “geocube” I am noticing a shift in raster i.e., pixel center is not in line with the input point.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Buffer snippet used is as follows

[image]

[image]

Note: If I gave like (xarray.Dataset, optional) , parameter to the make_geocube code is working fine. But I don`t want to use any like/template raster.
Problem 2: while converting many point files to raster geocube is taking very long time to save raster into disk (when compared with rasterio, features.rasterize) while using geocube I can convert 10 vector files to rasters (saving on disk) takes around 40+ seconds, while using rasterio it is taking around 25+ seconds. How to make this thing faster.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet, a sample input file, and the distance between the points.

Comment: @snowman2, hi I just edited my query, Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

On GIS SE, you should ask one question at a time, so I will answer problem 1.

Without a template raster, geocube determines the area of the raster by the bounding box of the input geometries and resamples the geometries to the raster. That is why it looks how it currently looks

If you want the raster cells to be centered on each point, I recommend doing a square buffer using geopandas so each point turns into a grid cell. [Creating square buffers around points using shapely?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314949/creating-square-buffers-around-points-using-shapely#314956)

```py
import geopandas
import pandas
from geocube.api.core import make_geocube

pdf = pandas.read_csv("nz_points1.csv")
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    pdf,
    geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(
        x=pdf.Longitude, y=pdf.Latitude, crs="EPSG:4326",
    ).buffer(0.005, cap_style=3),
)
out_grid = make_geocube(gdf, resolution=(-0.01, 0.01), measurements=["Temp"])
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried this way but the result is as same as previous

Comment: Can you add the code snippet you used to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the response! just added buffer snippet block. Please do let me know

Comment: Perfect, do you have sample input data you could share?

Comment: hi, please find the file @

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FTxP22faBQwD_iItmpW3i7eQOfpCQkpK/view

Comment: I tried it out and the results are definitely shifted for some reason. Will have to dig into it later.

Comment: I added a code snippet from what I attempted.

Comment: thank you! if you find a way do please let me know...

Comment: can you let me know reg (problem2) i.e, how to convert multiple vectors to rasters and save them as tiff fastly...if you wish to know my problem I will elaborate it further..thanks in advance

Comment: If I find a solution to problem 1, I will update the post. Also, I would recommend asking another question on GIS SE for problem 2.