# Create a shapefile that consists of square from a point CSV file that contains X,Y values using Python GeoPandas module

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, csv

Length of side of square should be 5 meter. Square has four points, therefore, to generate four points. However, polygon requires the last point to be the same as the starting point. So I need an additional point that is the same as the first point. I need to put these five points sequentially in a list and use this list to generate a polygon.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Coding questions here are expected to contain code. We are a problem-solving site, but your Question only contains a task, with no indication of effort to solve that task, or description of the problem encountered. Please [Edit] the Question to contain your best effort to solve the problem. Be sure to include the coordinate system in which your coordinates are framed.

Comment: `your_dataframe['geometry'].buffer(5, cap_style=3)` ([ref](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/314956/2856))