# Python - Creating a shapefile from a bounding box coordinates list

Tags: python, shapefile, extents

There is already few existing questions about this topic, but I unfortunately did not find something that could fix my problem...

I have a point Lat, Long coordinate i.e. Lat= 10 and Long = 10. I want to create a shapefile of a 0.5 degree bounding box around this point, so the bounding box should be as follow:

1. minimum Long= 9.75
2. minimum Lat = 9.75
3. maximum Long = 10.25
4. maximum Lat = 10.25

Does anyone knows how to do that in Python *without GIS software*?

I have no ESRI or QGIS. I thought that it would be possible to create a shapefile using bounding box coordinates with Python. The only info I have are the coordinates of the bounding box. I try using pyshp package pypi.org/project/pyshp but it is not obvious how should I proceed.

Comment: What have you already tried? in which GIS Software you want to use the tool?

Comment: There are already a few questions with good answers. Here's one for [ESRI](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29337/creating-square-buffer-around-point-feature-using-arcgis-for-desktop), and one for [QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34891/automating-drawing-of-polygons-square-around-number-of-points-in-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1). Both provide solutions with python and could be adapted to newer versions.

Comment: I think my question is unclear. I have no ESRI or QGIS. I thought that it would be possible to create a shape file using bounding box coordinates with python. The only info I have are the coordinates of the bounding box.

Comment: I try tio find a way using pyshp package https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/ but it is not obvious how should i proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, at least this worked for me, following the [Docs](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/) (which seem a bit outdated to me) and using the internal module documentation:

```
import shapefile as shp
from osgeo import osr

centroid_x = 10.
centroid_y = 10.
bbox_radius = 0.25
target_epsg = 4326
dst_file = r'd:\working\testing\test.shp'

w = shp.Writer()
# assign POLYGON (5) as shapeType
w.shapeType = 5
# add a "name" field of type "Character"
w.field('name', 'C')
# coordinates in clockwise rotation
w.poly([[[centroid_x - bbox_radius, centroid_y + bbox_radius],  # upper left
        [centroid_x + bbox_radius, centroid_y + bbox_radius],   # upper right
        [centroid_x + bbox_radius, centroid_y - bbox_radius],   # lower right
        [centroid_x - bbox_radius, centroid_y - bbox_radius],   # lower left
        [centroid_x - bbox_radius, centroid_y + bbox_radius]]]) # first point again
w.record('testpolygon')
w.save(dst_file)
# create ESRI prj-file
sr = osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromEPSG(target_epsg)
sr.MorphToESRI()
with open(dst_file.replace('.shp', '.prj'), 'w') as prj:
    prj.write(sr.ExportToWkt())
```

Unfortunately, 'pyshp' seems to lack the possibility to set a coordinate reference system, so you have to do that manually or use other modules, like [osr from osgeo](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html#create-projection). I added the lines to create the projection to the code.