# Drawing polygon constant km around point in lat/lon coordinates in QGIS3.12

Tags: qgis-3, point, buffer

I have a set of points in lat/lon coordinates over Europe representing pixels from a satellite dataset. I know each pixel has size 10x10km.

I want to draw a square polygon around each single pixel with the size 10*10km. I have tried reprojecting and then drawing a square around it using the "Rectangles, ovals, diamonds" tool. But every time I get this way too big square drawn around the results (see the image below). I am not exactly sure how to fix or even tackle this issue.

[image: Left: points, Right: drawn square]

I have tried the methods suggested [in this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34891/automating-drawing-of-polygons-square-around-number-of-points-in-qgis) as well.

Comment: I would guess they are only square in the original projection of the satellite image so you need to go back to that

Comment: Buffer them by 5000 m using a m-based CRS (probably EPSG 3857, since your AOI is very large) and set the buffer end cap style to `square` and the join style to `miter`.

Comment: Hi Erik, they're already in EPSG:3857 and I've reprojected them as well. Selecting that as CRS still gives the same issue.

Comment: What is the CRS of the point layer?

Comment: Geographical coordinates, WGS84.