# Clipping raster based on polygonised point marker using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

[image]

I would like to clip a big raster down to **individual trees** (i.e. each tree corresponding to each bounding box).

The square box you see here is a vector layer of multiple points, I merely changed the marker to a transparent square.

Clipping by raster will not work as the point is not a native polygon but a square marker.

Buffer works to polygonise multiple point markers. However, I still need to clip the big raster down to individual trees.

Are there any tools I can use to achieve this?

Comment: Check this out: 1. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34891/automating-drawing-of-polygons-square-around-number-of-points-in-qgis 2. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29337/creating-square-buffer-around-point-feature-using-arcgis-for-desktop

Comment: Do you want to create individual rasters for each tree or one big raster?

Comment: each tree. is there any tool i can use to do that now that i managed to polygonise multiple point markers into bounding boxes?

Answer (score 3):

Use these QGIS tools to generate a polygon geometry (square) for each individual point:

1. [Buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisbuffer)
2. [Minimum bounding geometry](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisminimumboundinggeometry)

An additional tool can be used to create a separate vector file for each polygon:

3. [Split vector layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgissplitvectorlayer)

And finally clip the raster image:

4. [Clip raster by mask layer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html#gdalcliprasterbymasklayer)

[image: points to squares]

Comment: TQ. it works. Still need to clip the big raster down to individual trees corresponding to their bounding boxes?

Comment: @DarrellLim See update.

Comment: I have more than 10,000 trees to clip. Split vector layer will create 10,000 files. Doing it one by one is too time consuming. :(

Comment: @DarrellLim You can create a python script or QGIS model to automate this process. Batch processing can also help you solve this problem.

Comment: Haven't written python script in QGIS before. a lot to read, which function to import, how to call each polygon that sit in geo package file. if you guys have any reference, that will be helpful. I suppose i will have to iterate through the polygon file, and call clip by raster for each i-polygon.

Comment: @DarrellLim Try this: https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing/modeler.html

Answer (score 2):

`Buffer` each point by half the length of the side of your marker box (in my case the box is 20 by 20 m, hence I buffered with 10).

Choose the `square` end cap style, and `miter` for your join style. This produced the hatched red boxes on the left side.

[image]

Comment: TQ. it works. Still need to clip the big raster down to individual trees corresponding to their bounding boxes?

Comment: The answer from @Comrade Che clips the raster using the resulting polygons